# Replacement of Method has_key in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to change this

```
def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_key('class') and not tag.has_key('id')
```

This function is from Python2 not for Python3

I had idea that

I changed this HTML document in a list like this

```
list_of_descendants = list(soup.descendants)
```

So I can get tags which contain class but don't id
it is about that find all tags with `class = blabla...` but not `id = ....`
I have no idea how I can handle this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey i solve this Problem.

What i had to do is

1.collect all the tags(BeautifulSoup) and all children of tags (contents)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc,"html.parser")
list_of_descendants = list(soup.descendants)
```

2.eliminate all NavigableStrings(cuz they can't accept has_attr() Methodes)

```
def terminate_navis(list_of_some):

    new_list = []

    for elem in list_of_some:

        if type(elem) == bs4.element.Tag:
            new_list.append(elem)
        else :
            continue

    return new_list 


new_list = terminate_navis(list_of_descendants)


def contents_adding(arg_list):
//this Method helps that get all the childrens of tags in lists again

    new_list = arg_list

    child_list = []

    for elem in arg_list:

        if elem.contents:

            child_list = elem.contents
            child_list = terminate_navis(child_list)
            new_list.extend(child_list)

        new_list = list(set(new_list))

    return new_list
```

3.filter all tags if they have attribute 'class' (has_attr) and if they don't have 'id'(also with has_attr)

```
def justcl(tag_lists):

    class_lists = []

    for elem in tag_lists:
        if elem.has_attr('class'):
            class_lists.append(elem)
        else :
            continue

    return class_lists

def notids(class_lists):

    no_id_lists = []

    for elem in class_lists:

        if elem.has_attr('id'):
            continue
        else :
            no_id_lists.append(elem)

    return no_id_lists
```

4. all this collected tags create as a list and print on the screen

print or using for loop and so on...

Comment: Can you please format all the code in your answer and update your question with what you want to accomplish. Specifically, with the example. I doubt you need all this messy code from your answer to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) says:

> I renamed one method for compatibility with Python 3:
>
> - `Tag.has_key()` -> `Tag.has_attr()`

Also, the exact same function is available in the [documentation here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

> If none of the other matches work for you, define a function that
>   takes an element as its only argument. The function should return `True`
>   if the argument matches, and `False` otherwise.
>
> Here’s a function that returns `True` if a tag defines the “class”
>   attribute but doesn’t define the “id” attribute:
>
> ```
> def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
>     return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('id')
> ```

Comment: ok i used ur suggestions, but there were another problem

AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'has_attr'

like i said i changes all Tag_elements in Beautifulsoup as a List and i applied that has_attr but that error message came out can u plz advice me more?

Comment: You're using the function on text (NavigableString) as well as tags. using `.has_attr` on text will raise the above error. Before calling the function, check if the list item is a tag. You can use `isinstance(item, Tag)` for that. Also, don't forget to import Tag from bs4 module.

Comment: If you can't implement that, add the code you're trying, in the question and I'll edit my answer accordingly.